# I need to change the code in file.class and then save it at same format (file.class)

Tags: java

I need to change the code in file.class and then save it at same format (file.class) ,please anyone can help me ?
thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change already compiled .class file without decompile?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14069082/how-to-change-already-compiled-class-file-without-decompile)

Comment: @Simze but why without decompiler ?

Answer (score 1):

decompile the class using java decompilers . I prefer JD-compiler.
create eclipse project and build project include other dependent class files in a jar.

Comment: I will try now and tell you

Comment: please can I sent to you my file to covert ,only first time?